# How to use graphql in Unity3D proyecto26 library?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphql, proyecto26.restclient

I implemented [GraphQL](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) on my API, however I don't know how to execute it on the libray I am using.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using Models;
using Proyecto26;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AuthController : MonoBehaviour {
  private readonly string basePath = "http://localhost:1337";
  public void Get(){
        currentRequest = new RequestHelper {
            Uri = basePath + "/graphql",
            Method = "GET",
            BodyString = "query {users {_id username email}}" //Use it instead of 'Body' to serialize using other tools
        };

        RestClient.Get<Auth>(currentRequest).Then(
            res => {

                string encodedString =JsonUtility.ToJson(res, true);                
                JSONObject jar = new JSONObject(encodedString);
                Debug.Log(jar);
            });

    }
}
```

It just returns error. It might be the "BodyString" but I am not really sure. Since this is my first time using [GraphQl](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) in Unity project. Please help me how to properly query this using [Proyecto26](https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient).

Comment: Could you show the error you get?

Comment: To make sure than server response correct info - try to use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). In this point you will exactly now which side produce error.

Comment: @derHugo I have finally able to get it worked brother.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this by using this library [Gazuntype/graphQL](https://github.com/Gazuntype/graphQL-client-unity) it is more convenient to use GraphQL now on my project. This solves my problem. It also uses simpleJSON to deserialized the response.